# How to get object attributes by name addressing in PHP

Tags: php

I have a table and submit button.
In the table there are some tds and trs.
For example I have the following td:
`<td name="td_1_name">qwerty</td>`
By clicking submit-button I want to see all the attributes of this td (height, backgroundcolor, value, etc).
What command will give me this information?

Comment: You can't do that in php, I can give you an example but with javascript

Comment: Yes, this must be done client-side with JavaScript.